# How to solve this pod issue "CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod" for iOS project?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I put new pods into project pod file and tried to install. Then I received this error in Terminal.

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx":
  In Podfile:
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Specs satisfying the `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the minimum iOS version to what's required by the requested podspecs. Add something like this to the `Podfile`:

`platform :ios, '13.0'`